# Railo on AWS Opsworks

Tags: railo, aws-opsworks

Does anyone have any information or experience deploying Railo (cfml) apps on AWS OpsWorks? It seems like it should be possible (similar to cloudbees or heroku) since Opsworks now supports java apps. I'm just having a hard time getting started.

Answer (score 0):

The official and active cookbook for this seems to be : https://github.com/ringgi/railo-cookbook. You're not specifying what specific issue you're having. You would need to modify any Chef community cookbook to implement on Opsworks. You would need to replace any mention of a role with the the name of the layer short name. That usually would be enough to get most simple cookbooks to behave with the Chef 11.10 version of the stack.

Most likely you would need to create a new cookbook with the community cookbook specified above + the required additional cookbooks mentions in the metadata.rb files.